# How to Disable Table resizing on big words in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this DIV

```
<div style="width:500px;"> </div>
```

I've inserted a table inside it

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If `<td></td>` contained normal words, even if 100 words with spaces between them, then table will maintain its size inside the div, but if a cell contained 1 word with like 100 letters, then the table will take a bigger size outside its parent div, `overflow:hidden;` is good to hide the table's enlargement, but I want the size to stay the same, and the cell to grow in `height`, like it usually do with normal words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`word-wrap` is an older IE specific CSS rule. To get word wrapping in modern browsers, use `white-space`. Also, setting `max-width` seems to help get things working.

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wXwkr/)

Comment: Thanks man this worked, but it will work with Google Chrome ?

Comment: I tested this in Chrome, yes. Chrome uses the CSS3 standard, `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 1):

Set the table's `max-width` to an absolute value, as specified by the `parent div`.

Try:

```
<table style="width:100%; max-width:500px;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap) property:

```
td {
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```